# RestAssured - Saving id from response for use in another method

Tags: java, rest-assured

Im using RestAssured to test our API. I created a POST method that will post a new piece of content. I capture the new id from the response in that same session and save it as a variable like so:

```
public String myId;

public void postSomething (){
    Response myResponse = 
    given ().
    when().contentType(ContentType.JSON).
    body(testData).
    post(postUrl);

    myId = myResponse.then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().path("result.id")}
```

The method works in that the new content is created and I can print out the newly created id of the content I just created.

The issue is that I need the id for my DELETE method that I use later on to clean up my test data. My delete method looks like this:

```
public void deleteTestData () {
Response myResponse = 
given().
when().
delete(deleteUrl + myId); }
```

This doesn't work for me. So in my deleteTestData() method, I did a

```
System.out.println(myId);
```

to see what the value was for myId, but it came back null. Please forgive my noobiness, but any help I can get to saving the Id from the post response to later use in my delete method is appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure your ID is found at `result.id`? Can you print out the response and post that too? `System.out.println(response.asString())` or something similar

Comment: Hi Adam, yes thats the right Json path. Im able to print it out perfectly fine when I run my POST method. Its trying to access that ID from another the other DELETE method that I posted above (all my API methods GET. POST, PUT and DELETE are in the same class).

Im able to print the full JSON response as a string as well as the ID field.

Comment: Can you print `myId` in your POST method to see that it is actually getting it? Also if you are running these as JUnit tests, the order is randomized by default.

Comment: I cant post the result here because the data is proprietary but it definitely does print. Also, I make sure to run my POST tests first and then my DELETE tests (I use testNG and Cucumber tags to run my suite).

Comment: In terms of test design, I would not run another 'test' but rather a Cucumber after hook in order to cleanup. Regardless, what about if you make `myId` static? It sounds like your test class instance is getting re-created between tests for some reason.

Comment: @AdamRosini  Yeah I just tried making the id field static

    public static String myId

 but still no luck. When I try to print out the myId field from the DELETE method, I get back a null value   =/

Comment: Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I made the variable in question static as mentioned in one of the comments, and this worked for me.

So something like:

```
private static String myId;
```

So it seems that multiple objects are being created from this class, perhaps something to do with multithreading. I'm also using @FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING), not sure if this is relevant.